# Is not function JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".add").click(function(event){
  save($(this).parent().attr("id"));
});
function save(docName){
  var inputs = $('#' + docName + ' input');
  var selects = $('#' + docName + ' select');
  var obj;
  console.log(inputs);
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    console.log(inputs[i]);
    obj[inputs[i].attr("id")] = inputs[i].val();
    inputs[i].val() = "";
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    obj[selects[i].attr("id")] = inputs[i].val();
    selects[i].val() = "";
  }
  firebase.database().ref().child(docName).push(obj);
}
```

Estou tentando criar uma funcao para adicionar um formulario dinâmico, porém o attr("id") fica dando um erro.
    "inputs[i].attr is not function".
 Alguem poderia me ajudar a resolver este problema?

Comment: Qual o resultado do `console.log`?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var divs = $(".div");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  console.log(divs[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="div" >1</div>
<div id="div2" class="div" >1</div>
<div id="div3" class="div" >1</div>
<div id="div4" class="div" >1</div>
```

Quando você faz isto, você não está percorrendo uma coleção de objetos `jQUery`, mas sim a coleção de `DOM` que o objeto `jQuery` está encapsulando.

O que você pode fazer, é verificar o id diretamente (sem utilizar `jQuery`)

```js
var divs = $(".div");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  console.log(divs[i].id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="div" >1</div>
<div id="div2" class="div" >1</div>
<div id="div3" class="div" >1</div>
<div id="div4" class="div" >1</div>
```

claro, se você precisar manipular cada objeto `DOM` como uma objeto `jQuery`, você terá de encapsular eles usando o `$`, apesar de ser possível fazer um `$(divs[i])`, é melhor que faça uso do `$.each`.

```js
var divs = $(".div");
divs.each(function (indice, elem) {
  var that = $(this);
  console.log(that.attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="div" >1</div>
<div id="div2" class="div" >1</div>
<div id="div3" class="div" >1</div>
<div id="div4" class="div" >1</div>
```

no exemplo acima, o `this` é justamente o objeto `DOM` que está encapsulado pelo `jQuery`.

**SUGESTÃO**

```js
$(".add").click(function(event){
  // passe o doc como argumento, utilize ele como escopo para a sua função.
  save($(this).parent());
});
function save(doc){
  // listando todos os inputs e selects dentro do doc.
  var inputs = $('input, select', doc);
  // você não estava iniciando a variavel obj.
  var obj = {};
  inputs.each(function () {
    // encapsulando o objeto DOM no jQuery.
    var input = $(this);
    obj[input.attr("id")] = input.val();
  });
  // val não é uma propriedade, mas sim uma função.
  inputs.val("");  
  // Quanto ao Firebase, não tenho como lhe ajudar.
  firebase.database().ref().child(doc.attr("id")).push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Eu alterei para
    obj[inputs[i].id] = inputs[i].value;
e esta dando esse erro. "Cannot set property 'nomeTime' of undefined"
OBS: NOme time é o id do input

Comment: Também fiz assim
obj[inputs.eq(i).attr('id')] = inputs.eq(i).val();

Comment: Consegui arrumar, muito obrigado.

Comment: @MrMinerin adicionei uma sugestão de codigo ao final da resposta,

Comment: @MrMinerin se estiver tentando aprender `JavaScript`, te aconselho fortemente começa pelo [`VueJS`](https://vuejs.org) do que pelo [`jQuery`](https://jquery.com), considero o vue mais fácil para aprender e mais útil ([Vue.js is easier to learn than jQuery](https://medium.com/js-dojo/vue-js-is-easier-to-learn-than-jquery-abbbb9c12cf8))